# How to differentiate which connection pool getting error on multiple connection pool?

Tags: java, c3p0

In our application we create multiple connection pools for different databases. But when there is an error in one of them like:

```
22/Dec/2016 08:26:03 WARN 62418062 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->3037t89l9ahxjv1s5760x|71619ce5]HelperThread#0] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool(L:1911) - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@5c9458eb – Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (5). Last acquisition attempt exception:
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:675)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:448)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:383)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:776)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:432)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:214)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
```

It is not possible to know which connection pool getting the error actually. Am I missing something? Is there any way to know which connection pool getting error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Connection Pool has a unique identityToken (`3037t89l9ahxjv1s5760x` in your example above). If you monitor your Connection pools via JMX, you can see which pools have this identityToken. You have programmatic access to all of your pools identityTokens via their `getIdentityToken()` method.

Comment: That will do the job. Thanks.